# php preg_match help getting facebook username/id from URL

Tags: php, regex, facebook, api, preg-match

I am trying to get the facebook username or id from a facebook url and was wondering if you could help me. I'm sure it's just a simple regex function but I have tried and can't seem to do it myself.

Here's what I've been trying to get from the url.

> http://www.facebook.com/**myusername**/

or the numerical id

> http://www.facebook.com/**2285652**/

I would be very grateful if anyone could help me achieve this via **PHP**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
preg_match('#https?\://(?:www\.)?facebook\.com/(\d+|[A-Za-z0-9\.]+)/?#',$str,$matches);
```

The pattern is versatile so it matches:

1. http and https URL's.
2. URL's with or without the `www` prefix.
3. URL's with or without the trailing `/`.
4. Matches Facebook numerical ID's.
5. Matches [Facebook's rules for usernames](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=105399436216001#What-are-the-guidelines-around-creating-a-custom-username?).

> Usernames can only contain alphanumeric characters (A-Z, 0-9) or a
>   period (".").

Comment: *Usernames can only contain alphanumeric characters (A-Z, 0-9) or a period (".")*. True. But the numerical ID can also be used.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. The pattern is matching numerical ID's as well.

Comment: It is fine. But it doesn't consider "pages".
what if a url is facebook.com/pages/12345?

Comment: I think this won't properly match usernames that start with a number ie. 01username01 (which is valid on facebook)

Comment: @Kentor The second part of the pattern will match usernames like that.

Comment: Why make a separate case for just numbers? If you match for alphanumeric, just numbers is a subset of that, isn't it?

Comment: I was either demonstrating regex "OR" -- or I simplified a pattern I was already using by removing two capturing groups that helped my other code determine if it was a numerical-only or alphanumeric match. Ex: `facebook\.com/(?:(\d+)|([A-Za-z0-9\.]+))`

Comment: Why is this not working for me? and link/str is www.facebook.com... `preg_match('#https?\://(?:www\.)?facebook\.com/(\d+|[A-Za-z0-9\.]+)/?#',$str,$matches)`

Comment: doesn't work for pages with UNICODE (like: `https://www.facebook.com/სარეკლამო-საწარმო-SabaDesign-927047470710565/?ref=ეგერერჰ` )

Answer (score 4):

Without regex:

```
$array = parse_url($url);
echo trim($array['path'], '/');
```